# The Span of a Countable Set is always Separable?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, separable-spaces

I wonder if the span of a countable set is always a separable subspace with the norm topology? It feels like a trivial question but how does one show this?

Namely, I start of with a countable set $\{ v_n \}_{n}$ and take the span of $\{ v_n \}_n$, name it the space $A$. Take $y \in A$, then $y = \sum_{i = 1} ^N c_i v_i$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$. How do we show that $y \in \overline{\{ v_n \}_n}$ closure?

Comment: I think the set of linear combinations of $\{v_n\}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the set of linear combinations of $\{v_n\}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Mason That should be an answer. Incidentally, note that that uses the separability of the (topological) field of scalars $\mathbb{R}$ as well.